# Make file not working c

Tags: compiling, make

```
A4: main.o testA4.o helper.o miscFunctions.o queueFunctions.o headerA4.h
    gcc -Wall -std=c99 main.o testA4.o helper.o miscFunctions.o queueFunctions.o

main.o: main.c headerA4.h
    gcc -Wall -std=c99 -c main.c -o main.o

testA4.o: testA4.c headerA4.h
    gcc -Wall -std=c99 -c testA4.c -o testA4.o

helper.o: helper.c headerA4.h
    gcc -Wall -std=c99 -c helper.c -o helper.o

miscFunctions.o: miscFunctions.c headerA4.h
    gcc -Wall -std=c99 -c miscFunctions.c -o miscFunctions.o

queueFunctions.o: queueFunctions.c headerA4.h
    gcc -Wall -std=c99 -c queueFunctions.c -o queueFunctions.o

clean:
    rm *.o
```

This is my make file but when I compile it this happens-

```
zali05@ginny:~/A4$ make
gcc -Wall -std=c99 main.o testA4.o helper.o miscFunctions.o queueFunctions.o
zali05@ginny:~/A4$ A4
bash: A4: command not found
zali05@ginny:~/A4$ A4:
bash: A4:: command not found
zali05@ginny:~/A4$ ./A4
bash: ./A4: No such file or directory
zali05@ginny:~/A4$ ./a.out
Begining A4 Program Testing...
Creating Initial List...
Enter a username:
```

It works with `./a.out`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The link/load command is missing the `-o A4` option.  You might want to write it as `-o $@`.  Similarly, you might write the object list in the command as `$^`, causing [GNU make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Variables.html#Automatic-Variables) to copy the dependency list.  (Alas, not all makes have [this feature](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Features.html#Features).)

Make will also provide a pattern for the compiles.  You could set `CFLAGS` and optionally `CC` and omit all the compile commands.

Also, you misformated the first line of your makefile when posting here.

Just to provide a complete result, if I were writing this makefile (and not using [automake](https://www.gnu.org/software/automake/) or [makedepend](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E88353_01/html/E37839/makedepend-1.html) (use one!), and targeting to not be GNU make specific), I would probably write:

```
A4_OBJS = main.o testA4.o helper.o miscFunctions.o queueFunctions.o 

CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -Wall -std=c99

A4 : ${A4_OBJS}
        ${CC} ${CFLAGS} ${LDFLAGS} -o $@ ${A4_OBJS}

main.o : main.c headerA4.h
testA4.o : testA4.c headerA4.h
helper.o : helper.c headerA4.h
miscFunctions.o : miscFunctions.c headerA4.h
queueFunctions.o : queueFunctions.c headerA4.h

clean :
        rm *.o A4
```

Comment: A link to some source on make's `$@`, `$^` and such could be useful, if you have one at hand.

Comment: @ilkkachu Gnu make manual at: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/   Automatic variables at: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Variables.html#Automatic-Variables

Comment: Thank You!!! :D

Comment: @ZainAli: you are quite welcome.  If this is a good answer for you, you might want to "accept" it.  (You should read the tour at https://unix.stackexchange.com/tour for more information (and your first badge).)